# How to forward slot time when testing in solana - anchor

Tags: solana-program, anchor-test, solana-test-validator

i'm trying to write a test for a program that requires n - number of slots to have passed before executing. Please is there a way to skip/forward slots using anchor? I'm using `solana-test-validator` to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently.  The `solana-test-validator` does not expose any way to advance the slot number. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/19822 is tracking the issue, but it's over a year old.

Anchor encourages writing tests in JS, but if you can write Rust tests, the `solana-program-test` crate allows you to move slots forward in time.  Here's an example of how to do it:

```
use solana_program_test::ProgramTest;
let program_test = ProgramTest::default();
let mut context = program_test.start_with_context().await;
context.warp_to_slot(10).unwrap();
```

Example taken from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/program-test/tests/warp.rs